# Insert Results From SqlDataReader into HTML5 Database

Tags: database, html, offline

I have an asp.net web application (c#) in visual studio 2010 that is heavily data intensive.  As my users will mostly be accessing the site from mobile devices, a certain level of offline functionality is required.  My goal would be to load some of the most needed data at login into an HTML5 database to be used throughout the site even when offline.  I am good to go on the cache manifest, I just need to manage the data that may need to be access for certain portions of the site to function.

Update: I have gotten as far as creating and inserting into web SQL tables using clientscript.registerstartupscript in my .cs file. After login, I run a SQL select on the server to grab relevant information for that user and insert into Web Sql table. From this point on, I want to be operating client side with only the data from the web SQL table that is now populated. I can Select * From My Web Table but I am stuck on how to databind it to my gridview.

Anyone have any samples or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gave up on gridview and just used an html table.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/03/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript.html